# Loop through top-level headings in Emacs Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, iteration

I want to apply (org-id-get-create) to every top-level heading in the buffer. How can I loop through all top-level org-mode headings in the current buffer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `org-map-entries` to apply a function to all the entries in a org-mode buffer matching a search.  In this case the search "LEVEL=1" will match all top level headlines.  The function you specify will be called without arguments with the point on the headline.  So `(org-map-entries 'org-id-get-create "LEVEL=1")`  will apply the `org-id-get-create` function to every `LEVEL` 1 headline.

Comment: Golly, the docs could be improved.

"MATCH is a tags/property/todo match as it is used in the agenda tags view. Only headlines that are matched by this query will be considered during the iteration.  When MATCH is nil or t, all headlines will be
visited by the iteration."  Why not add a cross-reference to the place where this format is actually documented? ... If, indeed, it is actually documented anywhere?

Comment: @JoeCorneli The documentation for the query syntax is here: https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties  You have to click through a lot of pages to get everything

Comment: Thanks for the link! LEVEL seems specifically a bit buried!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an built-in org function for that, the following function should solve it.

```
(defun adl/org-top-level-heading-cycle ()
  (interactive)
  (if (not (search-forward-regexp "^* " nil t))
      (progn
    (goto-char 1)
    (search-forward-regexp "^* " nil t))))
```